# Disabled Allow Guest Checkout does not allow order in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, guest-checkout

I am using `Magento ver. 1.9.2.1`. For `Allow Guest Checkout` enabled magento store allow to order to guest or registered user.

But when I set to `No` for `Allow Guest Checkout` option then registered user also unable to order. When user submit order then `onepage/checkout` page redirect registered user to `cart` page.

Is there any other setting for disable guest checkout?

Comment: if it redirects to cart page it is a sign of a possible error. enable logging System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings and check logs - do you see anything strange there while you try to check out?

Answer (score 8):

By default the guest checkout in Magento is enabled and visitors can place an order without registering to the website. Some websites require mandatory login for placing orders, and this default feature should be turned off to disallow guest checkout.

To disable guest checkout, navigate to:

**System > Configuration > Sales section > Checkout > Checkout Options**

Set Allow Guest Checkout to No